# Will arp table on the host (linux) will refresh after no of failure?

Tags: network, networking, linux

Let say I have a remote hostA and remote hostB. Initially hostA has an IP address of ADDR1 and hostB has an IP address of ADDR2. Now clientA made a successful connection with hostA using ADDR1. clientA stored hostA MAC address in the arp table. Next, I have exchanged the IP address of hostA and hostB.

What will happen if I made a second call from clientA to ADDR1 before ARP table entry timeout? Will this call fails or ARP table will refresh after no of failure or anything else?

I am using IPv4 stack.

Comment: Of course, we are supposing that "remote" is actually on the same network, otherwise ARP does not come into play on clientA (but rather on the router that connects the network of hosts A and B to the rest of the world).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection will fail. The packet will be switched to Host A and host A will receive it, because the destination MAC is correct. But the IP stack will drop the packet since the IP address doesn’t match the address of host A.

Comment: Aren't there mechanisms that update the ARP table other than an actual ARP request/response pair? Like receiving a frame with an IP/MAC pair not in the ARP table? I kind of remember something like that somewhere in the past, but I'm not fully certain of whether that actually is the case, was the case, was specific to some OS...?

Comment: Well, I should search before posting comments... Gratuitous ARP enables a host to inform other hosts on the network of a new IP/MAC combination. Some operating systems supposedly use it, no idea how widespread this is nowadays.

Comment: @jcaron is your opinion is the connection will not fail?

Comment: It’s possible that when you configure the new address, the host will send out a GARP ( gratuitous ARP). That’s highly dependent on the OS and maybe the particular version. It may also depend on how you change the address.

Comment: @KarthikNedunchezhiyan if the host sends a gratuitous ARP with the new info, then the connection should not fail. However, I have no idea which OS (if any) actually sends gratuitous ARP and under what conditions.